# Looping multiple listed data frames into a single function

Tags: r, list, lapply, mclapply

I am trying to execute the function varipart() from the package ade4. I am trying to use the same number dataframe from each list in the different parts of the same function. I need to pass this for each set of dataframes.

```
########### DATA BELOW
    d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
      d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
      d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(2, 1, 2), y2 = c(5, 6, 4))
      spec.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)

      d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(20, 87, 39), y2 = c(46, 51, 8))
      d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(30, 21, 12), y2 = c(61, 51, 33))
      d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(2, 11, 14), y2 = c(52, 16, 1))
      env.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)

      d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(0.15, 0.1, 0.9), y2 = c(0.46, 0.51, 0.82))
      d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(0.13, 0.31, 0.9), y2 = c(0.11, 0.51, 0.38))
      d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(0.52, 0.11, 0.14), y2 = c(0.52, 0.36, 0.11))
      spat.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)
###############
      # I have tried two ways 
      library(parallel)
      library(ade4)

        output_varpart <- mclapply(spec.list, function(x){
          varipart(x, env.list, spat.list, type = "parametric")
        })

        output_varpart <- mclapply(x, function(x){
          varipart(spec.list[[x]], env.list[[x]], spat.list[[x]], type = "parametric")
        })

        for(i in 1:length(x)){
          results <- varipart(spec.list, env.list, spat.list, type = "parametric")
        }
```

None of these methods work! Please be gentle, I'm new to list syntax and looping. Errors are "Warning message:
In mclapply(output.spectrans.dudi, function(x) { :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code" and "Error in x * w : non-numeric argument to binary operator", respectively.

Comment: Why don't they work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I updated my question! They were the standard error message for mclapply function and then "Error in x * w : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: Does ```varipart``` take a list as a second and third argument? I can't call the function by itself unless all three arguments are data frames.

Comment: It does not say that it takes a list, but does say dataframe or matrix. I was hoping that I could create a function to isolate each data frame. Almost like lapply.

Comment: Hmm. Three lists with three elements each, do you want 9 calls to varipart? That's tougher, but you can try to get ```mapply``` to work first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but I'll explain a bit how `lapply` (and `mclapply`) work, because it feels like you're mixing up what the role of `x` is. First, this should work:

```
output_varpart <- mclapply(1:3, function(x){
      varipart(spec.list[[x]], env.list[[x]], spat.list[[x]], type = "parametric")
    })
```

But why?
The function `lapply` means: apply a function (2nd argument) to all values in a list (first argument). So `lapply(list('Hello', 'World', '!'), print)` will do

```
print('Hello')
print('World')
print('!')
```

and it will return a list of length 3 with the results (the return of `print` is the value that was printed)

But quite often, there is not one function that does exactly what you want. You can always define a function, like this:

```
my_vari_fun <- function(index) {
  varipart(spec.list[[index]], env.list[[index]], spat.list[[index]], type = "parametric")
}
```

You can then call it like `my_vari_fun(1)`, and it doesn't matter at all if the argument is called `x` or `index`, or something else. I'm sure you get it. So a next step would be

```
output_varpart <- lapply(list(1,2,3), my_vari_part)
```

The disadvantage of this is that it takes multiple lines of code, and we probably won't use `my_vari_fun` again. So that's the reason we can provide an *anonymous* function, we just give a function to lapply without assigning it to a name. We just replace `my_vari_fun` with it's "value" (which happens to be a function).

However, outside this function, `x` doesn't mean anything. We could as well have called it any other name.

We just need to tell lapply what values to input: `list(1,2,3)`. Or simpler as a vector, which `lapply` will convert: `1:3`

By the way, I've just inserted `3` here, but for the general case you can use `1:length(spec.list)`, you just have to make sure all lists are the same length.

Finally, I've talked about `lapply` now, but it all works the same for `mclapply`. The difference is only under the hood, `mclapply` will spread its work over multiple cores.

## Edit: debugging

In debugging, there is more difference between `lapply` and `mclapply`. I will first talk about `lapply`.

If there is some error in your code that gets executed inside the `lapply`, the entire `lapply` will fail, and nothing gets assigned. Which sometimes makes it hard to spot exactly where an error takes place, but it can be done. A simple workaround may be feeding `lapply` just parts of your input, to see where it breaks.
But R also comes with some debugging tools, where execution is freezes as soon as an error is encountered. I find `recover` the most useful tool.

You can set it by `options(error=recover)`, and every time an error is encountered, it gives you a backwards list of the function that threw the error, by which function it was called, by which function that was called, ...
Then you can choose a number to explore the environment in which that function was running. When I try to emulate your error, I get this:

```
Error in x * w : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

 1: source("~/.active-rstudio-document")
 2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
 3: eval(ei, envir)
 4: eval(ei, envir)
 5: .active-rstudio-document#20: lapply(1:3, function(x) {
    varipart(spec.list[[x]], env.list[[x]], spat.list[
 6: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 7: .active-rstudio-document#21: varipart(spec.list[[x]], env.list[[x]], spat.list[[x]], type = "parametric")
 8: as.matrix(scalewt(Y, scale = scale))
 9: scalewt(Y, scale = scale)
10: apply(df, 2, weighted.mean, w = wt)
11: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
12: weighted.mean.default(newX[, i], ...)
```

A lot of them are internal functions by R, and you can see what `varipart` does: it passes on stuff to lower functions, who pass it on, etc.

For our purposes, we want number 6: here the `lapply` calls your function, with the `i-th` input value.
As soon as we enter `6`, we get a new prompt, that reads `Browse[1]>` (in some cases it may be another number), and we are in the environment as if we just entered our

```
function(x){
  varipart(spec.list[[x]], env.list[[x]], spat.list[[x]], type = "parametric")
}
```

Which means typing `x` will give you the value for which this function fails, and `spec.list[[x]]` etc. will tell you for which inputs `varipart` failed. Then the final step is deciding what this means: either `varipart` is broken, or one of your inputs is.

In this case, I noticed I can get the same error by having one of the columns in the `data.frame` something else then `numeric`. But you'll have to look whether that is your problem as well, but debugging becomes a whole lot easier if you've figured out where the problem is.

#### With mclapply

`mclapply` runs on multiple cores, which means that if there is an error in one core, the other cores still finish their jobs.

For calculations where a forked process encountered an error, that error will be the return value, in the form of a `try-error`-object.
But note that that will be the case for other iterations by the same core as well. So if for `mclapply(1:10, fun)`, `fun(1)` will throw an error, in the case of 2 cores, all odd inputs will show that error.

So we can look at the return value, to narrow our search down:

```
sapply(output_varpart, class)
```

The error(s) is/are in the iterations where the output-class is try-error, but we can't know exactly which one.

How to practically solve it depends on the size of the calculations.
If they were really extensive, it may be worth it to keep the values that did succeed, and narrow it down again by re-running only the failed parts.
Or if I just see one `try-error`, we don't need look any further.
But usually, I find it most useful to change the `mclapply` to a regular `lapply`, and use the approach above.

Comment: The function worked on the sample data but not on my real data lol. However, this explanation is really helpful!

Comment: Did you see the comment on my other post?

Comment: Not yet, but now I've extended my answer. Short version: I think one of your inputs is broken, but you need to figure out which one it is (in your real data)

Comment: The difference that the spec.list had to be transformed like this ... spec.dudi <- mclapply(spec.list, function(x){
          dudi.pca(x, scale = F, scannf = F)
        }) # this caused the error

Comment: Wow. There was a single NA in one of the lists! Fixed. Thanks so much for your incredible assistance.